# How can I exclude the limit from being $- \sqrt{B}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, monotone-functions

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Assume $B$ is a positive number. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined recursively by $x_1 = 1,$ and $$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(3B + x_n^2)}{3 x_n^2 + B}.$$ Prove that $x_n \to \sqrt{B}.$

**My trial:**

I assumed that $x_n \to L,$ and I got from $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(3B + x_n^2)}{3 x_n^2 + B}$ that $L = \pm \sqrt{B}.$ But I want to exclude the case of $L = - \sqrt{B},$ so I decided to prove that the given sequence is increasing **(I did not manage to show this)** and since the first term is $x_1 = 1$ then the limit cannot be negative.

Can anyone show me please how to prove that the given sequence is increasing?

**EDIT:**

I realized the answer to my title of the question. I am now searching for a proof of the monotonicity of the sequence please?

Comment: Well, you can easily show if $x_n$ is positive, $x_{n+1}$ is positive. Can you show a positive sequence can't converge to a negative number? (The real problem is assuming $L$ exists. Some sequences don't converge to any value.)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah but the question is asking to prove that the limit equals a specific value, so I understood then that the limit exists. Are you saying that I should prove that the sequence is increasing and bounded above first?

Comment: I actually do not know how to show what you stated in your first statement @ThomasAndrews

Comment: No, you need to show the limit exists, too. When a problem says "show the l8mit is $9,$" it is not saying "assuming the limit exists, show the limit is $9.$"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to your question [Proving the monotonicity of $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(3B + x_n^2)}{3 x_n^2 + B}.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4553344)

If you already know that $(x_n)$ converges to $L$, then in fact
$$L = \dfrac{L(3B + L^2)}{3 L^2 + B} \tag{1}$$
which gives $L = \pm \sqrt B$. But clearly $L \ge 0$ since all $x_n > 0$ (since the quotients in the recursion cannot produce values $\le 0$). This shows that $L = - \sqrt B$ is impossible.

But $(1)$ is based on the **existence** of
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n  \tag{2}$$
which requires a proof.

In the answer to the linked question it is shown that the function $f(x) = \dfrac{x(3B + x^2)}{3 x^2 + B}$ is strictly increasing so that we get

1. $(x_n)$ is strictly increasing for $B > 1$.
2. $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing for $B < 1$.
3. $x_n = 1$ for all $n$.

In case 3.  $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 1$.

In case 2. $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists because all $x_n > 0$.

In case 1. we can easily show by induction that all $x_n < \sqrt B$ which proves that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists.

The base case $n = 1$ is trivial since $x_1 = 1$. If $x_n < \sqrt B$, then
$$x_{n+1} = f(x_n) < f(\sqrt B) =  \sqrt B .$$

Comment: (since the quotients in the recursion cannot produce values $\le 0$)  ...... Is this because $\{x_n\}$ is always assumed to be a positive sequence (but usually not stated) or because of what?

Comment: @MathIgnorance Formally you have to use induction to prove that all $x_n>0$. The base case is trivial and if $x_n>0$, then the quotient in the recursion is also positive.

Comment: Oh, I see that makes much much much more sense ....... thank you very very much for your 2 answers ..... they relieved my mind :) ...... I was sooo confused before reading them  :)