# Proving the monotonicity of $x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(3B + x_n^2)}{3 x_n^2 + B}.$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, monotone-functions

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Assume $B$ is a positive number. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be defined recursively by $x_1 = 1,$ and $$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_n(3B + x_n^2)}{3 x_n^2 + B}.$$ Prove that $x_n \to \sqrt{B}.$

**My question is:**

I do not know how to proof the monotonicity of the sequence by the usual ways (calculating $x_{n+1} - x_n$ or $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ or the derivative of the given sequence after defining it as a function). Can someone help me in showing this monotonicity, please?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140038/discussion-on-question-by-mathignorance-proving-the-monotonicity-of-x-n1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\mathbb R_+ = (0,\infty)$ denote the set of positive real numbers and  $$f: \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+, f(x) = \dfrac{x(3B+x^2)}{3x^2+B} = \dfrac{x^3 + 3Bx}{3x^2+B} .$$
We get
$$f'(x) = \dfrac{(3x^2 + 3B)(3x^2+B) -(x^3+3Bx)6x}{(3x^2+B)^2} = \dfrac{9x^4 +9Bx^2 +3Bx^2 +3B^2 - 6x^4 -18Bx^2}{(3x^2+B)^2} \\
= \dfrac{3x^4 -6Bx^2 +3B^2}{(3x^2+B)^2} = \dfrac{3(x^2 -B)^2}{(3x^2+B)^2} .$$

Thus we have $f'(\sqrt B) = 0$ and $f'(x) > 0$ for $x \ne \sqrt B$. In other words, $f$ is strictly increasing.

Since $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, we see

1. $x_{n+1} > x_n$ implies $x_{n+2} = f(x_{n+1}) > f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$. Thus, if
   $$x_2 > x_1 = 1 \tag{1} $$
   then $(x_n)$ is strictly increasing. Since $x_2 = \dfrac{3B+1}{3+B}$, we have $x_2 > 1$ iff $3B+1 > 3+B$. The latter means $B > 1$.
   Hence $(x_n)$ is strictly increasing for $B > 1$.
2. $x_{n+1} < x_n$ implies $x_{n+2} = f(x_{n+1}) < f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$. Thus, if
   $$x_2 < x_1 = 1 \tag{2}$$
   then $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing. As above we see that $(2)$ holds iff $B < 1$.
   Hence $(x_n)$ is strictly decreasing for $B < 1$.
3. In case $B = 1$ we see that all $x_n = 1$.